Pair-wise assignment but neighbours can't be paired together
I have a set of N elements and I would like to assign them pairwise using a function f(n) where n is the index of the element and f(n) is the index of its pair.
The elements are grouped four by four, like {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, etc... The last group may have less than four elements since N is not necessarily divisible by 4.
I want to assign them pairwise but I want to minimize the number of elements paired with an element of his group.
What are good approaches to this or analog problems ? What field of mathematics can help me to approach that problem ?
Thanks.

The name of this topic is combinatorial design

I assume N is even. I suspect that there is always a solution with zero elements paired to a member of their own group, for N>6.

If $N\geq 8$ (and even), there always exists a neighbor-free pairing. For example shift (and mod by $N$) the numbers by $4$. I.e. $1$ goes with $5$ and so on $N$ goes with $4$. In fact any shift between $4$ and $N-4$ will work. And of course there are many many other neighbor-free pairings. Interesting question then arises how many are there?
Here is a recursive function to calculate the number of these neighbor-free pairings when there are groups of various sizes. Let the number of groups of each size $1,2,\dots, k$ be given by the vector $a$. The idea is to first take the "first person" (this isn't a choice, since we don't want the pairs (neither between them nor inside them) to have an ordering but we're picking them in order so something must be fixed and we fix it so that the first person is always the one with the lowest remaining index). Then we pick the pair. This can be picked from any group other than the first person's group. The group-size-vector gives us the number of ways this can be done (remember to disregard the first person's group). Decrement the group sizes accordingly and recurse. It's kind of a hassle to write this in maths notation but here's a Python-code. And here's a brute-force version that I used for checking the answer. Also for the case $k=2$ there is this OEIS A053871. And isn't this the number of perfect matchings of the complete multipartite graph (where parts are the groups)?
UPDATE: I wonder if this can be used!? The complement of the multipartite is a disjoint sum of completes. This has a certain flavour of rook polynomials to it. We take a product of the polynomials of the groups and then calculate some sort of sum from its coefficients (this is what the integration does).
UPDATE2: Yes, this is the case! For $N=2n = 4q + 2r$ where $r \in \{0,1\}$, the number is given by
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} (x^4-6x^2+3)^q (x^2-1)^r dx
$$
This can be calculated by expanding the polynomial with trinomial theorem and then the integration brings about double factorials.
